# How to edit the New row template in Blazorise.Datagrid?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazorise

I am trying out `Blazorise datagrid` to display rows and add new rows. I would like to customize the Salary field such that there is a + button on the new row form. This + button will retrieve the Salary based on certain criteria using AJAX call. Is it possible to do?
[image]

I took the screenshot from https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/templates

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an `EditTemplate` and defining the Select and Button components manually.

A quick example that will give you an idea:

```
<DataGridColumn Field="Salary">
  <EditTemplate>
    <Select TValue="decimal" SelectedValue="@((decimal)context.CellValue)" SelectedValueChanged="@(v=>context.CellValue = v)"
      ...
    </Select>
    <Button Color="Color.Primary>Add</Button>
  </EditTemplate>
</DataGridColumn>
```

Comment: But then how the value is changed in the DB ? I am not able to find any example about the RowUpdated attribute